# How to extract the uris lists by regex?

Tags: python, regex

In my python code , I get strings from the text file like :

```
a =  "[{'index': '1', 'selected': 'true', 'length': '0', 'completedLength': '0', 'path': '', 'uris': [{'status': 'used', 'uri': 'http://www.single.com'}]}]"

b ="[{'index': '1', 'selected': 'true', 'length': '0', 'completedLength': '0', 'path': '', 'uris': [{'status': 'used', 'uri': 'http://www.mirrors.com'}, {'status': 'used', 'uri': 'http://www.mirrors2.com'}]}]"

c ="[{'index': '1', 'selected': 'true', 'length': '103674793', 'completedLength': '0', 'path': '/home/dr/Maher_Al-Muaiqly_(MP3_Quran)/002.mp3', 'uris': []}, {'index': '2', 'selected': 'true', 'length': '62043128', 'completedLength': '0', 'path': '/home/dr/Maher_Al-Muaiqly_(MP3_Quran)/004.mp3', 'uris': []}, {'index': '3', 'selected': 'true', 'length': '57914945', 'completedLength': '0', 'path': '/home/dr/Maher_Al-Muaiqly_(MP3_Quran)/003.mp3', 'uris': []}]"
```

I want to get the text of the value uris , the output should looks like :

```
a = [{'status': 'used', 'uri': 'http://www.single.com'}] 

b = [{'status': 'used', 'uri': 'http://www.mirrors.com'}, {'status': 'used', 'uri': 'http://www.mirrors2.com'}]

c = [[],[],[]]
```

Many hours I spent in failed trials to get this result by using the string functions ,

```
uris = str.split('}, {')
for uri in uris :
     uri = uri.split(',')
     # and so on ...
```

but , it work so bad especially in the second case , I hope that anyone can do it by regex or any other way.

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: Seems like python list literals. Aren't they?

Comment: @tabebqena, `c` is invalid; contains `,  ,` near end.

Comment: typo , I have correct it .

Comment: @tabebqena Read the text of the tag you use (hover it with your mouse).

Comment: sorry , I have add it after your comment , but it isn't saved for any reason , I add and save it just now .

Comment: I have correct many typo in the question and add "my trials" and my language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all python literals. You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). No need to use regular expression.

```
>>> a =  "[{'index': '1', 'selected': 'true', 'length': '0', 'completedLength': '0', 'path': '', 'uris': [{'status': 'used', 'uri': 'http://www.single.com'}]}]"
>>> b = "[{'index': '1', 'selected': 'true', 'length': '0', 'completedLength': '0', 'path': '', 'uris': [{'status': 'used', 'uri': 'http://www.mirrors.com'}, {'status': 'used', 'uri': 'http://www.mirrors2.com'}]}]"
>>> c = "[{'index': '1', 'selected': 'true', 'length': '103674793', 'completedLength': '0', 'path': '/home/dr/Maher_Al-Muaiqly_(MP3_Quran)/002.mp3', 'uris': []}, {'index': '2', 'selected': 'true', 'length': '62043128', 'completedLength': '0', 'path': '/home/dr/Maher_Al-Muaiqly_(MP3_Quran)/004.mp3', 'uris': []}, {'index': '3', 'selected': 'true', 'length': '57914945', 'completedLength': '0', 'path': '/home/dr/Maher_Al-Muaiqly_(MP3_Quran)/003.mp3', 'uris': []}]"
```

---

```
>>> import ast
>>> [x['uris'] for x in ast.literal_eval(a)]
[[{'status': 'used', 'uri': 'http://www.single.com'}]]
>>> [x['uris'] for x in ast.literal_eval(b)]
[[{'status': 'used', 'uri': 'http://www.mirrors.com'}, {'status': 'used', 'uri': 'http://www.mirrors2.com'}]]
>>> [x['uris'] for x in ast.literal_eval(c)]
[[], [], []]
```

Comment: Very good , excactly what I need .

Answer (score 0):

in javascript you can do this

```
a = a.replace(/^.*uris[^[]*(\[[^\]]*\]).*$/, '\1');
```

if php would be this a way

```
$a = preg_replace('/^.*uris[^[]*(\[[^\]]*\]).*$/', '\1', $a);
```

edit: well I see, it wouldn't do your complete task for 'c' -.-